# Dynamic population of drop down list in html and php

Tags: php, html

I am working on student attendance system project
for that i am using html and php 
I need the solution for this problem

i have 4 drop down list 
In the `first drop down list` contains **Civil Engg,Comp Engg etc.....and so on**.
In the `second dropdown list` subject names are there that are stored in mssql database and depending on the value selected in first drop down I need to populate the subject from the database
like

```
select * from allsubjects where branch='civilengg';
```

so please any give me the solution for this scenario

Comment: We will not do the entire project for you, if you want help you need to provide more information, like a JSFiddle/pastebin/codepen with the html and js that you have tried. It sounds like you are looking for an ajax way but you have not shared what have you done, so we dont know where are you stuck. Remember that SO is to get help when you cant make progress, its not to get someone to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax/)'s a tutorial about Dynamic Dependent Select Box Using Ajax and jQuery that might help you

Another solution is this:

Put an id in your `<select name="X">` code like `<select name="X" id ="X">`

Put another select like `<select name="Y" id="Y">`. Which will be blank.

put this jquery in your page.

```
$("X").on("change",function(){
    var x_value=$("X").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:{subject:x_value},
        type: 'post',
        success : function(resp){
            $("#Y").html(resp);               
        },
        error : function(resp){}
    });
});
```

In your ajax.php add the query.

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_query("SELECT * from allsubjects WHERE branch =".$_POST['branch']);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($row))
    echo '<option value="' . $row2['subId'] . '">' . $row2['subName'] . '</option>
?>
```